# AWS-SDK Node JS High Latency

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, event-loop, amazon-elasticsearch

I am facing problem while using aws-sdk *amazons elasticsearch* in my node app. I am getting high latency when having performance testing using some tools like *jmeter* or *seige*. My requests initially show low latency but when the number of requests increase the latency also increases. Need Help ! Thanks

Comment: Start by figuring out where the latency is occurring. Is it the Node app itself or the calls to Elasticsearch?  One way to do this is AWS X-Ray. But you could just log the start and end timestamp of each action.

Comment: it is the aws http-client that is taking time